# Enviar objeto complexo da view para controller ASP MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, asp, controller

Na minha View tenho um model complexo onde exibo em uma table apenas alguns campos.

Neste model tenho uma outra lista chamada Tracks onde não exibo seu conteúdo. Repare na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso receber o objeto (var Item) que é o meu AlbumViewModel no controller com todas as propriedades, ou seja: Band, Id, Image, Name, ReleasedDate e Tracks.

No meu controller a lista de Track está vindo vazia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como recebo o objeto completo em meu controller.

Obrigado.

**Minha View exibindo o conteúdo de uma Partial View**

```
@model IsoFM.WebSite.Models.BandViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<br />

<center><h2>Details Band</h2></center>

<div>

    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.Image)" style="height:200px;width:200px;" />
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Biography)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Biography)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumPlays)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumPlays)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<center><h2>Albums</h2></center>


@Html.Action("Details", "Album", new { idBand = this.Model.Id });



<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>
```

**Controller da Partial View**

```
using AutoMapper;
using IsoFM.Domain.Entities;
using IsoFM.Infra.Reporitory;
using IsoFM.WebSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IsoFM.WebSite.Controllers
{
    public class AlbumController : Controller
    {
        AlbumRepository _albumRepository = new AlbumRepository();
        BandRepository _bandRepository = new BandRepository();
        // GET: Album
        [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = Mapper.Map<List<Album>, List<AlbumViewModel>>(_albumRepository.Obter());

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "idBand")]
        public ActionResult Details(string idBand)
        {
            if (idBand == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(idBand) == true)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            if(Discografia.BandCollection == null)
                Discografia.BandCollection = Mapper.Map<List<Domain.Band>, List<BandViewModel>>(_bandRepository.ObterFull());

            var albumDetais = Discografia.BandCollection.Where(b => b.Id == idBand).FirstOrDefault().AlbumList;

            List<AlbumViewModel> listaAlbum = new List<AlbumViewModel>();

            foreach (var item in albumDetais)
            {
                listaAlbum.Add(item.FirstOrDefault());
            }

            return PartialView(listaAlbum);
        }

    }
}
```

**Objeto da Partial View**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace IsoFM.WebSite.Models
{
    public class AlbumViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleasedDate { get; set; }
        public string Band { get; set; }
        public TrackViewModel[] Tracks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Objeto TrackViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace IsoFM.WebSite.Models
{
    public class TrackViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }        

    }
}
```

**Código VIEW onde preciso passar todo o objeto para controller, conforme exibido na imagem 1**

```
@model IEnumerable<IsoFM.WebSite.Models.AlbumViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleasedDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" style="height:200px;width:200px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleasedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Track", new { @id = item.Id, @Name = item.Name, @Image = item.Image, @ReleasedDate = item.ReleasedDate, @Band = item.Band, @Tracks = item.Tracks }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**CONTROLLER Onde preciso receber o objeto da View Acima!**

```
using AutoMapper;
using IsoFM.Domain.Entities;
using IsoFM.Infra.Reporitory;
using IsoFM.WebSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IsoFM.WebSite.Controllers
{
    public class TrackController : Controller
    {
        BandRepository _bandRepository = new BandRepository();
        [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult Details(AlbumViewModel model)
        {

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inclua o codigo da sua view, e da view model, evite utilizar imagens do código.

Comment: Adicionei o trecho de código da View / Controller. Coloquei a imagem para exemplificar melhor!

Comment: faltou a AlbumViewModel

Comment: Adicionei os objetos!

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você postou sua view de exibição, não o form para criação ou edição

Comment: Pronto Leandro agora está tudo!

Comment: Como eu falei antes, você tem views apenas de visualização, o seu problema é mandar dados da view para a controller ou da controller para a view?

Comment: Mandar os dados da View para o Controller, ou seja quero mandar o objeto AlbumViewModel para o Controller: TrackController, com todas as propriedades: Band, Id, Image, Name, ReleasedDate e Tracks (Array de Tracks).